# AWS SDK for PHP how to get list of reserved Instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-php-sdk

I can successfully get list of EC2 instance.

using below code

```
$conf_aws = array();
$conf_aws['credentials']= array(
    'key' => $config['AWS']['configkey'],
    'secret'  => $config['AWS']['configsecret'],
);

$conf_aws['region'] = 'ap-southeast-1';
$conf_aws['version']='latest';
$ec2Client  = \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory($conf_aws);
$list = $ec2Client->DescribeInstances();
```

Can anybody suggest how to get list of reserved instance.

Comment: Here use this $ec2->describe_reserved_instances_listing();

Comment: Thanks works good !!

Comment: Please mark my answer correct then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this edited code and it will work.

```
$conf_aws = array();
$conf_aws['credentials']= array(
    'key' => $config['AWS']['configkey'],
    'secret'  => $config['AWS']['configsecret'],
);

$conf_aws['region'] = 'ap-southeast-1';
$conf_aws['version']='latest';
$ec2Client  = \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory($conf_aws);
$list = $ec2->describe_reserved_instances_listing();
```